# Could not find or load main class net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.Main

Tags: ruby, proxy, browsermob

Github link:-

```
https://github.com/jarib/browsermob-proxy-rb
```

Am creating a proxy using browsermob proxy by following:-

```
require 'selenium/webdriver'
require 'browsermob/proxy'

server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new("/path/to/downloads/browsermob-proxy/bin/browsermob-proxy") #=> #<BrowserMob::Proxy::Server:0x000001022c6ea8 ...>
server.start
```

While executing "server.start", it throws error like below:-

```
Error: Could not find or load main class net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.Main
BrowserMob::Proxy::Server::ServerDiedError: unable to launch the server (rerun with :log => true to see process output)
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@v-qa/gems/browsermob-proxy-0.2.0/lib/browsermob/proxy/server.rb:75:in `wait_for_startup'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@v-qa/gems/browsermob-proxy-0.2.0/lib/browsermob/proxy/server.rb:34:in `start'
    from (irb):13
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put 'lib' folder with 'broowsermob-dist' jar file near the 'bin' folder.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem.

I had only two files `tryout-browsermob.rb` and `browsermob-proxy` together under same folder and referenced as below:

```
server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new("./browsermob-proxy")
```

But it turned out that having only a single `browsermob-proxy` binary file wasn't enough.

The `lib` folder is also needed after extracting the release zip file downloaded from https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/releases.

It's better just extract the release zip into a folder and keep all files with the original folder structure.

```
/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4
   /bin
   /lib
   /ssl-support
   browsermob-core-2.1.4-javadoc.jar
   browsermob-core-2.1.4-sources.jar
   browsermob-rest-2.1.4-javadoc.jar
   browsermob-rest-2.1.4-sources.jar
```

Then in the `.rb` file, reference the binary like

```
server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new("./browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy")
```

If under Windows, use fully qualified path.

```
server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new("D:\\browsermob\\browsermob-proxy-2.1.4\\bin\\browsermob-proxy.bat")
```